# how to rank/row_number the following table using SQL

Tags: sql

The table will be ordered by userid and timestamp in ascending order. Example is like following:

```
|userid|url                      |timestamp              |
|------|-------------------------|-----------------------|
|AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 06:20:10.000|
|AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 10:18.57.000|
|AAA   |https://yahoo.com        |2023-01-31 14:56:15.000|
|AAA   |https://baidu.com        |2023-01-31 14:56:33.000|
|AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 17:05:54.000|
|AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 17:25.56.000|
|BBB   |https://google/search.com|2023-01-31 09:13:02.000|
|BBB   |https://yahoo/finance.com|2023-01-31 10:00:00.000|
```

One userid could visit same url at different time. If they are in sequential order and time difference is <=30 minutes, record it as same session_id. If they are in sequential order and time difference is > 30 minutes, record it as different session_id.
The final output I want is like following:

```
|session_id    |userid|url                      |timestamp              |
|--------------|------|-------------------------|-----------------------|
|AAA-1         |AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 06:20:10.000|
|AAA-2         |AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 10:18.57.000|
|AAA-3         |AAA   |https://yahoo.com        |2023-01-31 14:56:15.000|
|AAA-4         |AAA   |https://baidu.com        |2023-01-31 14:56:33.000|
|AAA-5         |AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 17:05:54.000|
|AAA-5         |AAA   |https://google.com       |2023-01-31 17:25.56.000|
|BBB-1         |BBB   |https://google/search.com|2023-01-31 09:13:02.000|
|BBB-2         |BBB   |https://yahoo/finance.com|2023-01-31 10:00:00.000|
```

I tried dense_order() function but it will record all the same urls as one same session_id even they are not in sequential order.

need help on this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the database you are using. Anyway, it wouldn't change seriously from database to database, so this sample with postgreSQL would do:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    userid      text,
    url         text,
    "timestamp" timestamp
);

INSERT INTO myTable
    ("userid", "url", "timestamp")
VALUES ('AAA', 'https://google.com', '2023-01-31 06:20:10.000'),
       ('AAA', 'https://google.com', '2023-01-31 10:18:57.000'),
       ('AAA', 'https://yahoo.com', '2023-01-31 14:56:15.000'),
       ('AAA', 'https://baidu.com', '2023-01-31 14:56:33.000'),
       ('AAA', 'https://google.com', '2023-01-31 17:05:54.000'),
       ('AAA', 'https://google.com', '2023-01-31 17:25:56.000'),
       ('BBB', 'https://google/search.com', '2023-01-31 09:13:02.000'),
       ('BBB', 'https://yahoo/finance.com', '2023-01-31 10:00:00.000');

with lags (userid, url, ts, lag) as
         (select userid, url, "timestamp", lag("timestamp", 1) over (partition by userid, url order by "timestamp")
          from myTable t1),
     adjusted as
         (select userid,
                 url,
                 ts,
                 case
                     when lag is not null and
                          ts - lag <= interval '30 minutes' then lag
                     else ts end rts
          from lags),
     ranked (userid, url, ts, rnk) as
         (select userid, url, ts, dense_rank() over (partition by userid order by rts)
          from adjusted)
select userid || '-' || rnk as session_id, userid, url, ts
from ranked
order by userid, ts;
```

| session_id | userid | url | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA-1 | AAA | https://google.com | 2023-01-31 06:20:10 |
| AAA-2 | AAA | https://google.com | 2023-01-31 10:18:57 |
| AAA-3 | AAA | https://yahoo.com | 2023-01-31 14:56:15 |
| AAA-4 | AAA | https://baidu.com | 2023-01-31 14:56:33 |
| AAA-5 | AAA | https://google.com | 2023-01-31 17:05:54 |
| AAA-5 | AAA | https://google.com | 2023-01-31 17:25:56 |
| BBB-1 | BBB | https://google/search.com | 2023-01-31 09:13:02 |
| BBB-2 | BBB | https://yahoo/finance.com | 2023-01-31 10:00:00 |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qM1tcrEP)